# Extracting lines from a file that match a list of IDs

Tags: shell, loops, grep, extract

Hopefully I'm going to make sense here...

I have a huge file - each line represents data from a different individual.  What I want to do is to grep (or extract) out information (lines) for certain individuals - I don't want to keep greping out the individuals individually then appending it all together at the end but I was curious whether there is a loop I can set up by proving a text file with the IDs (ie ID001, ID002... ID100) or some variable that is unique to each individual.  I'm fairly new to programming so I'm not sure what I should be googling/looking for to get the answer - but is this possible in Shell?

Apologies for what might be a simple question.

Thanks!

EDIT 1:  I'm adding a little more info here:
format might be different but essentially the file is a genetics file and has the following format:

```
FAM001 ID001 A A T T TC T A…… A G
FAM001 ID002 A A T T C C A G…… T C
FAM004 ID003 A A T G T G A A…… A G
.
.
FAM100 ID100 G A C T C G T G…… T G
```

Is it possible to set up a loop, say, similar to/includes this:

```
for f in $( cat ~/FAMID.txt )
```

With the FAMID.txt as:

```
FAM001
FAM050
FAM087
```

to be able to run a certain analysis on the individuals with a certain FAMID ID  but only running the program on the families in the list provided?

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: This kind of questions need : sample input, sample output, what you expect.

Comment: @user2726449 : just for curiosity, the sequence 'G A C T C G T G…… T G' seems like that of a DNA, is it ?

Comment: @blackSmith Yeah it is.  I'm trying to run a loop; I'm trying to run a certain code on the family members in the families listed.  Not all at once but one family at a time.

Answer (score 1):

This is all you need:

```
grep -wFf FAMID.txt data.txt
```

where:

- `-f FAMID.txt` tells grep to read the patterns from the file
- `-F` tells grep that the patterns are plain strings so it can pick an appropriate matching engine
- `-w` tells grep to only match patterns that form a whole word (so if you accidentally get "FAM" in the pattern file, you don't match every line of the data file)

Comment: Thanks for this - but is there a way to run a loop.  Say, running a certain code on family members one family at a time (for only those families that are in the list provided)?

Comment: I'd use the above as the first filter on your big data file, then you can parse the results.